# Insert Photo Gallery Into Post Blog (Yii)

Tags: php, yii, include, ckeditor, nivo-slider

I really need help.

This is my situation:

-I make blog using yii

-I use extension editMe, and everything is going well with text and picture

-This is my blog look's like: http://oi58.tinypic.com/1z67es4.jpg

-This is when we create new post using editMe: http://oi62.tinypic.com/iwhix5.jpg

Now, my question is, how to insert a gallery photo like nivoslider into that post??
I mean how to insert a script code like `<?php include 'slideIndex.php'; ?>` into text area editMe??

Comment: your comment to my answer has proven that your question wasn't asked properly, nobody could have ever answered this question...

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you need to do in order the slider to work, but all that is very nicely detailed in nivoslider's documentation page here: http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider, they even have a video tutorial. ;)

In general terms, if you're using any proper image viewer, they should all have documentation like this one, so try and follow those, and let us know if you encounter any issues during implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.
I found the solution. I make 1 field in DB and check if the data==file name. :)

Comment: this has absolutely nothing to do with your question, how were you even expecting people to be able to answer this...?

Comment: Sorry brother, i am very confused. So i keep looking for other way to show the slide.